# How to write numbers in other language in web?

Tags: web, unicode, ascii, persian

My website has two language, English and Persian. When I use Persian language and I write some number, the number shows in English language

For example when I write 67 in Persian unfortunately it show me 67 in English but I write it in Persian (My font is Arial)  :
[image]

How to write numbers in Persian?

Comment: How exactly are you "writing in Persian"? Those are distinct characters which can be perfectly represented separately and should not/will not automagically switch over.

Comment: I don't know why when I write persian numbers show me English number

Comment: Those numbers are Arabic, not Persian. For example, the Arabic six is ٦ while the Persian six is ۶. You can see the difference. Those are different unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persian numbers have different unicode codes, f.e english zero 0 is code 48 (0x0030 hex), but persian zero 0 is code U + 06F0, so you have to enter numbers in proper unicode codes (different chars). Also your font have to support these codes (not all fonts support such numbers).

Persian numbers starts at unicode 0x06F0 (0, ۰) to 0x06F9 (9, ۹) while english numbers are 0x0030 (0) to 0x0039 (9).

**How to enter these characters** (in Windows)

If you do not have proper language support to enter these characters on your keyboard, you can enter them in Wordpad (standard application in Windows) or in Microsoft Word by entering four characters (hexa) of the code (f.e. 06F9) and pressing alt+x shortcut. four-character word will be converted to proper unicode character.

Comment: OK, I know there, But I don't know why when I write persian numbers show me English number

Comment: @Kermani I have updated the answer. Unfortunately, I do not have language support for Persian to try other methods, but I believe that you can configure something in "Regional Settings" in Control Panel in Windows. Although Microsoft Word method works ok if you need just few numbers to enter somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I always have problem with Persian alphabet in computer